# Django - Form not populating in models but no error in console

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm creating a Django application and am having a bit of difficulty with creating 'activities' via the frontend.   (CRUD application)

Previously, I had issues related to the `ForeignKey` for the host; which I was using the extended `AllAuth models` (named `UserProfile`) and the errors for this do appear to have been resolved, however, there is still something going wrong in the functionality.

I'm currently struggling to get the submitted data to pass from the form through to the backend, but there are no errors in my console/terminal window when I'm running the application.

`views.py`:

```
def create_activity(request):
    userprofile = get_userprofile(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ActivityForm(request.POST, instance=userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('activities')
    else:
        form = ActivityForm(instance=userprofile)
        context = {
        'form': form,
    }
        return render(request, 'activities/new_listing.html', context)
```

Along with my `forms.py` file:

```
from datetime import date
from django import forms
from .models import Activity

from .widgets import DatePickerInput, TimePickerInput

class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ('name', 'date',
                  'start_time', 'end_time', 
                  'location', 'description')
        labels = {
            'name': 'Activity Type',
            'date': 'Date of Activity',
            'start_time': 'Start Time',
            'end_time': 'End Time',
            'location': 'Location',
            'description': 'Description',
        }
        widgets = {
            'date' : DatePickerInput(),
            'start_time' : TimePickerInput(),
            'end_time' : TimePickerInput(),

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the forms `action` in your HTML and assigned it to the `create_activity` function URL in `urls.py`.

For example, in your `new_listing.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url '**yourFunctionUrl**' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}

   {{ form.as_p }}

</form>
```

And in `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('SomeURL', views.create_activity, name='**yourFunctionUrl**'),
```